# Как создать png из jpg с обрезкой фона в Java(Android)?

Tags: java, android, png

Имеем jpg файл. Требуется сохранить его в формате png, при этом обрезать фон, т.е. сделать его прозрачным.
В какую сторону смотреть? Возможно есть готовые библиотеки для этого?
Также каким образом работать с фоновым цветом, т.н. чувствительность?

Comment: Вам для начала нужно для себя дать определение, что является "фоном". Как определить, фон это, или нет. Как только дадите определение, сразу можете по нему начинать писать алгоритм, или искать готовое решение.

Comment: В моем случае фон - (желательно) сходные оттенки одного цвета, окружающие искомое изображение в середине. Пользователь выбирает точку на исходном изображении, которая является фоном и выбирает чувствительность, т.е. границы оттенков выбранного цвета. Далее смотрю изображение попиксельно. Если цвет пикселя входит в заданный промежуток оттенков, то делаем его прозрачным (transparent, если не ошибаюсь). Далее сохраняем полученный массив пикселей в bitmap и сохраняем все это. Скажу честно - по моему жуткий велосипед, поэтому прошу помощи специалистов.

Comment: Ну так вы работаете уже с потоком, в Android есть оба метода компрессии этих форматов - делайте, что хотите. Открыли поток -> настроили alpha -> компрессия в png. 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
Но что-то мне подсказывает, что вам другое нужно

Comment: Если смотреть в общем, то вы пытаетесь сделать фотошоп для Android, не имея никаких знаний и ресурсов, насколько я понял. на практике, если вы и реализуете какой-то велосипед, то он будет работать жудко медленно. Такие задачи надо решать при помощи NDK, как минимум. А лучше вообще на стороне сервера. Ваша задача слишком сложна как для вас, так и для меня.

Comment: Shwarz Andrei, спасибо за ответ. Вектор ясен.

Comment: metalurgus, нет желания сделать порт Фотошопа для Андроид. Стоит задача реализовать только данную функцию, т.е. сделать png из jpg

Comment: Я по алгоритму могу подсказать, что надо непо всем пикселям проходится, а только по смежным со стартовой точкой, до тех пор, пока цвет следующего пикселя попадает в диапазон.